# Define filename of attachment

Tags: filenames, attachment, allure

I'm attaching screenshots like this:

```
@Attachment(value = "Screenshot", type = "image/png")
public byte[] makeScreenshot(BufferedImage image) {
    ...
    return imageInByte;
}
```

The filename is beeing generated automatically and looks something like this 4282ae45-5ca1-4621-91c7-ce8a3a2bd58c-attachment.png.
Is there a way to change this filename? I'd like to refer to the screenshots in a second test and would need it to have a specific name like "http_www_homepage_html.png".

Comment: Hi there! What is the reason for refer to the screenshots from other test?

Comment: I have to test runs, one with a previous release of a website, one with the new release. In both runs I take screenshots of all pages. In a third run I compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the method

```
    public static String generateAttachmentName() {
       return UUID.randomUUID().toString() + CONFIG.getAttachmentFileSuffix();
    }
```

in ru.yandex.qatools.allure.utils.AllureResultsUtils, this is a fixed mechanism which can't be altered without major code changes, I guess.

I'm using `TestSuiteReader reader = new TestSuiteReader(new File(TEST_FOLDER));` to read the results of the previous test runs to get the path to the attachments. This solved my issue.